# youtube-dl How to get subtitles filename?

Tags: download, youtube, filenames, youtube-dl

With youtube-dl, you can get the video filename (`--get-filename`) and you can get the list of available subtitles (`--list-subs`), but it doesn't seem to have anyway to retrieve the file name of the downloaded subtitles.

If I want to only download the subtitles of a video, I'd do something like this:

`youtube-dl.exe --write-sub --sub-format best --sub-lang en --skip-download -o "~/Videos/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" YOUTUBE_URL`

Then, the subtitle would download as
`TITLE-en.EXTENSION`

But if I do something like this

`youtube-dl.exe --write-sub --sub-format best --sub-lang en --skip-download -o "~/Videos/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" YOUTUBE_URL --get-filename`

It only gives me the filename of the video.

Any help?